# Android: Gradient as fill color influences stroke color

Tags: android, android-studio, ui-design

I have assigned a gradient as a fill color to my vector drawable. Strangely, the gradient has now also been adopted as the stroke color, although I actually assigned a separate color for the stroke color. Does anyone know how it comes to this?

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="28dp"
android:height="16dp"
android:viewportWidth="28"
android:viewportHeight="16">

<path
    android:strokeWidth="0.5"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:pathData="M0,0
                      v16
                      M28,0
                      v16
                      M6,12
                      q-2,0 -2,-2
                      v-4
                      q0,-2 2,-2
                      h9.567
                      a6,6 0 1,1 0,8
                      z">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient
            android:startY="8"
            android:startX="4"
            android:startColor = "#FF333333"
            android:endY="8"
            android:endX="26"
            android:endColor = "#FFFF0000"
            android:type="linear">
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>

</vector>
```

Comment: can you please post some code?

Comment: @oziomajnr For a better understanding I have also added the code

Comment: why not assign the gradient from the cml where the vector drawable is used... android:tint="@drawable/my_grdient"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same Paint for the vector drawable fill color and the stroke color, you need to assign the correct color every time before you actually do the drawing. Or you can consider using different Paint to avoid the problem.

[update] Ok, forget the above paragraph. With the code, I find it works if changed to this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="28dp"
    android:height="16dp"
    android:viewportWidth="28"
    android:viewportHeight="16">


    <path
        android:pathData="M0,0
                      v16
                      M28,0
                      v16
                      M6,12
                      q-2,0 -2,-2
                      v-4
                      q0,-2 2,-2
                      h9.567
                      a6,6 0 1,1 0,8
                      z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:startY="8"
                android:startX="4"
                android:startColor = "#FF333333"
                android:endY="8"
                android:endX="26"
                android:endColor = "#FFFF0000"
                android:type="linear">
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>

    <path
        android:strokeWidth="0.5"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M0,0
                      v16
                      M28,0
                      v16
                      M6,12
                      q-2,0 -2,-2
                      v-4
                      q0,-2 2,-2
                      h9.567
                      a6,6 0 1,1 0,8
                      z">
    </path>
</vector>
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: But that's not the case with me. For a better understanding I have also added the code